# Stopped at vector cache

Tags: debugging, arm, trace32, lauterbach

I am using a Lauterbach trace32 debugger for S9KEAZ128ALMH controller. And when debugging I'm getting a message Stopped at Vector catch.

I used the skez.cmm script to configure flash. The same works for another sample project.

Comment: What is your question?